# Installed Selenium on Ubuntu, but can't import it

Tags: python, ubuntu, vps

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS(HVM)-free tier to run my python script. I connect with the Key to the server with Putty. I manage my files loaded onto the the server using FileZilla. After I install python on the server with `sudo apt install python3` I install Selenium using `pip install -U selenium`. The process is a success. I then load my python script through FileZilla  and then try to run the python script. Like most that have asked I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BinaryAutomation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Now please understand this. I have tried to install selenium manually by installing and unachieving the file found [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files), which basically downloads the setup to be loaded using `python setup.py install`. I do not have permission to paste anything under tmp\usr\bin I have tried that. How do i get around this problem?

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-pip` and install python3 requirement using ` pip3 install -U selenium`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have other versions of python/pip installed. Install packages using `pythonx -m pip install ...` with `pythonx` your python version (`python3` I presume) to avoid installing packages for a version of python that you're not using to run your scripts.

For more details check: [Why you should use `python -m pip` - Snarky](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu generally follows [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), which says that the command `python` should be Python 2. So, use `python3` instead of `python`. That extends to PIP too, so I would say to use `pip3` instead of `pip`, but that method is becoming outmoded; use `python3 -m pip` instead.

This is assuming you haven't changed the `python` and `pip` commands.